# How to allow a certain domain or URL to bypass Brave Shield on a specific website, when it's embedded there?

Tags: rules, adblock, brave, ublock-origin, ublock

I want to make a custom filter rule for Brave Shield and according to [this help page](https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/6449369961741), "Brave is broadly compatible with uBlock Origin's filter rule syntax." along with a link to [the documentation](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Static-filter-syntax). But this is all too overwhelming for me and I don't know what I should be looking for when I just want to do a simple thing: allow a domain or URL to bypass the Brave Shield on a particular website.

Example:

1. I go on `website.com`.
2. `website.com` embeds content from `external.com`
3. `external.com` is blocked by Brave Shield so its content doesn't load properly on `website.com`.

How do I write a custom filter that allows `external.com` to bypass Brave Shield but only when it's embedded on `website.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Generally adding `@@||external.com^` inside the `brave://adblock`
custom rules should work for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely looking for [`domain`](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Static-filter-syntax#domain) with negation. So:

```
||external.com^$domain=~website.com
```

That will block `external.com` everywhere except on `website.com` in uBlock origin. So it might not work for certain scenarios of e.g. `iframe` doing further requests.

[It's supposed to be supported](https://github.com/brave/adblock-rust/issues/1) also in Brave. Can't say if it works with your quite inexplicit example.

---

Slightly more accurate but once again not fully supported in Brave:

```
||external.com^$document
||external.com^$domain=~website.com,3p
```

This blocks both root `document` (to cover `external.com` directly) and 3rd party scripts (to cover `external.com` in iframes etc. without affecting 1st party requests) in uBlock Origin.

But even though Brave supports `$document` according to the link above, it doesn't seem to work in latest version for me. I'd recommend raising an issue there. Or just using uBlock Origin as it's a much better adblocker.

Comment: It does work on uBlock Origin, but sadly does not on Brave Shield so I assume this is just unsupported in Brave

Comment: Pretty sure it's impossible within Brave currently then.